# Unicode Hexadecimal code points for PHP

Tags: php, javascript, unicode

Does anybody have a Unicode to Hexadecimal code points (as seen in the link below which is Javascript) for PHP?

http://people.w3.org/rishida/tools/conversion/

Why reinvent the wheel if I don't have to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this myself. Used mb_convert_encoding to convert to HTML entities and converted from there.